# How to Resize Recycler View Item When Vertical Scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, vertical-scrolling

I have a recycler view (Horizontal Scrollable) where One item is always in center. I want to resize this recycle view item when vertical scroll on this view. And After scrolling, The centered item will show as the first item and the size of the view will decrease also while scrolling up. Here I add initial and final view of my requirement.

[image: Initial and After Vertical scroll]

Currently I can detect scroll using GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() And i can resize the view based on vertical scroll. But i don't have any controll of recycle view and its animation. And I also don't know after scroll up which item will show at first position.

Can you please help my how can i Do this kind of animation on recycler view?